# Drawing equal paths from geographic points?

Tags: algorithm, travelling-salesman

I have 10'000 geographic points (POS), 10 salesmen, and one starting point. **To avoid discrimination between salesmen, everyone should travel the same distance and the same number of points of sale.**

My goal is to:

1. assign a path for each salesman starting from the starting point with the same number of geographic points (POS).
2. Each path should have the same distance.

My solution is sort an array of GPS coordinate points by distance and then assign each point to a path until the end of the loop, but doubt this will work..

What is the easiest algorithm to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: classic travelling salesman problem ([TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)).  If you're just trying to achieve a least cost path for each salesman, you'll obviously need to use least cost path rather than tsp.  You need a network topology for routing algorithms.  I recommend [pgrouting](https://pgrouting.org/) or maybe look at the [routing options in QGIS](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/routing/)

Comment: Also, it is pretty unlikely that each path will be the same distance because your points do not appear to be evenly distributed.

Comment: @jbalk Thank you for your answer, the main concern is to avoid discrimination between salesmen, everyone should travel the same distance and the same number of POS.